# Car gets stuck to the ground when trying to go upwards

Tags: unity, physics

When I tried to go on top of the container, my car got stuck.

Here is a picture of the situation:

[image]

- I am using `4200` for mass and defaults for drag and angular drag.
- I'm using the `WheelCollider` component.

I've done some research and one thing I found said to change drag and angular drag, but that didn't fix my problem. Another suggestion was to change The value of the wheel collider.  I prefer not to change that because fixing the wheel collider was a really hard problem. Also, I don't think it's a wheel collider issue.

Comment: We'll need more information to troubleshoot effectively. Please edit your question to walk us through the steps required to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem. That is: every line of code and every step of scene setup a reader would need to follow to build the simplest version of this, starting from a new, empty project. Once we can reproduce the exact issue you're facing, we can test potential solutions to be sure they'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much information, but I can think of two possible causes based on your screenshot:

1. If you can back off of the ramp after you get stuck, it's possible that the motor doesn't have enough torque to drive up a ramp. Try increasing the torque.
2. If you *can't* back off of the ramp after you get stuck, it's possible that the colliders for the bumpers are too low (or the wheel colliders are too high), and the wheels don't work because the truck is sitting on the bumpers.